# A fundamental notational question in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

What does it mean when someone writes $\text{Pr}((X_1, X_2) \in A)$ for two i.i.d. random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$? I have two interpretations, and I am not sure if they are equivalent. To be more precise, let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two i.i.d. real-valued random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be a Borel set.

1. $\text{Pr}((X_1, X_2) \in A)$ means
   $$
   \mathbb{P}((X_1, X_2) \in A) := \mathbb{P} \{\omega \in \Omega : (X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega)) \in A\};
   $$
2. or $\text{Pr}((X_1, X_2) \in A)$ means
   $$
   \mathbb{P} \otimes \mathbb{P}((X_1, X_2) \in A) := \mathbb{P} \otimes \mathbb{P} \{(\omega_1, \omega_2) \in \Omega^2 : (X_1(\omega_1), X_2(\omega_2)) \in A\},
   $$
   which in turn can be written as
   $$
   \int_\Omega \mathbb{P} \{\omega_1 \in \Omega : (X_1(\omega_1), X_2(\omega_2)) \in A\} \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega_2).
   $$

Comment: It is the former; this is part of why we generally fix a single huge probability space at the beginning of an analysis rather than changing it as we go. The latter formulation doesn't support joint distributions properly.

Comment: Thanks. That's my belief too. But do you know how to simplify the expression in the second formulation?

Comment: The second formulation gives you the case where $X_1,X_2$ are independent (but it is an inconvenient formulation in terms of doing operations like addition etc. of random variables)